# IF statement using delayed expansion?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

I have a piece of code that looks something like this(Delayed Expansion is enabled):

```
    for /l %%y in (1,1,%variable%) do (
     set /a rand=!random! * 100 / 32768 + 1
     echo !rand!
     if !rand! GEQ %chance% (
      set /a var=%var%+%varx%
     )
    )
```

the `echo !rand!` part displays the number, but `if !rand! GEQ %chance%` just sees !rand! as a string, not as its value. So even if !rand! is bigger than %chance% it still skips the command.

The weird part is no matter how many times `!rand!` is greater than `%chance%` at the end of the loop var increases by `%varx%` only once. What should be done here so that the `IF` statement sees `!rand!`'s value?

Comment: you seem to know about delayed Expansion and how to use it. Just also do it for `!var!` instead of `%var%`

Comment: It seems to be working now. Thank you so much! So in a loop I should use exclamation points in an IF and SET?

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stephan says in his comment - you know enough to use delayed expansion within a loop when expanding `random` and `rand`. Why aren't you using it with `var`? The value of `%var%` is constant within your loop. You need `!var!` to see the dynamic value that exists at each iteration.

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,%variable%) do (
  set /a rand=!random! * 100 / 32768 + 1
  echo !rand!
  if !rand! GEQ %chance% (
    set /a var=!var!+%varx%
  )
)
```

But there is another solution. SET /A knows how to expand variables on its own, without `%` or `!`. Note that `!random!` is still needed because `random` is not a true environment variable.

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,%variable%) do (
  set /a rand=!random! * 100 / 32768 + 1
  echo !rand!
  if !rand! GEQ %chance% (
    set /a var=var+varx
  )
)
```

Or you could use the `+=` operator

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,%variable%) do (
  set /a rand=!random! * 100 / 32768 + 1
  echo !rand!
  if !rand! GEQ %chance% (
    set /a var+=varx
  )
)
```

If you want optimal performance, you could do all computations within one SET /A, without any need for IF. But this is pretty extreme, and not very readable:

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,%variable%) do (
  2>nul set /a "rand=!random!*100/32768+1, 1/(rand/chance), var+=varx"
  echo !rand!
)
```

`var` is only incremented If `rand` is greater than or equal to `chance`. If `rand` is less than `chance`, then you get a division by 0 error (hidden by the redirection of stderr), and SET /A does not proceed any further.